# how to design a language switcher in web application chrome.18n

Tags: jquery, localization, internationalization, google-chrome-app

Our software is written by html, css, Javascript using Chrome.i18n. 
our language is in the folder _locales/en/messages.json. Now, i need to internationalize our product such as Chinese version. so, it will be  _locales/zh/messages.json.. now the problem is coming, i did not find any function to switch locales.... no matter what i do. it always open the en/messages.json.

console.log(chrome.i18n.getUILanguage()); always print out en

SO is there a function like chrome.i18n.setUILanguage(zh)?

it seems that chrome app find there language path by your computer Ui language..

so, i just want to design a drop down list for user to switch language

here is my html code

```
<select class="dropdown" id="selectlanguage">
  <option id="enBtn" value="en">English</option>
  <option id="zhBtn" value="zh">简体中文</option>
</select>
```

javascript code

```
    'use strict';

function localize() {
    var localized = 0;

    var translate = function(messageID) {
        localized++;

        return chrome.i18n.getMessage(messageID);
    };

    $('[i18n]:not(.i18n-replaced').each(function() {
        var element = $(this);

        element.html(translate(element.attr('i18n')));
        element.addClass('i18n-replaced');

    });

    $('[i18n_title]:not(.i18n_title-replaced').each(function() {
        var element = $(this);

        element.attr('title', translate(element.attr('i18n_title')));
        element.addClass('i18n_title-replaced');
    });

    $('[i18n_value]:not(.i18n_value-replaced').each(function() {
        var element = $(this);

        element.val(translate(element.attr('i18n_value')));
        element.addClass('i18n_value-replaced');
    });

    $('[i18n_placeholder]:not(.i18n_placeholder-replaced').each(function() {
        var element = $(this);

        element.attr('placeholder', translate(element.attr('i18n_placeholder')));
        element.addClass('i18n_placeholder-replaced');
    });

    return localized;
}
```

need a javascript code to change locales...................

Comment: chrome.i18n uses the [UI language you set in Chrome's settings](https://superuser.com/questions/1239876/to-change-google-chrome-language). You can't change it programmatically. You'll have to use another internationalization library or write one yourself.

Comment: do you know how to write a function change locales?

Comment: The locale is changed automatically when the UI language is changed in Chrome's settings.

Comment: i need a language switcher in app rather than change Chrome setting...

Comment: You'll have to use another internationalization library or write one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on wOxxOm, it looks like this uses the settings in chrome://chrome/settings/languages, so not only are you not able to switch languages programatically, you don't want to do that and shouldn't have to. Try querying that setting and setting your localization file based on what it returns.